# How can I crop a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, editing, ffmpeg

I have an MP4 file of a screen recording that I need to crop. How can I do this with `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 581, accepted):

Use the [`crop` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4
```

Where the options are as follows:

- use "-vf" or -"filter:v" - depending on your version of ffmpeg/avconv
- `out_w` is the width of the output rectangle
- `out_h` is the height of the output rectangle
- `x` and `y` specify the top left corner of the output rectangle (coordinates start at (0,0) in the top left corner of the input)

### Original image

[image: original image]
<sub>Original 320x240 image</sub>

### How out_w, out_h, w and h fit into the picture

[image]

### Example 1

[image: 80x60]

To crop a 80×60 section, starting from position (200, 100):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "crop=80:60:200:100" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

- The audio is [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) in this example, so re-encoding is avoided.

### Example 2

[image: bottom right quarter]

To crop the bottom right quarter:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "crop=in_w/2:in_h/2:in_w/2:in_h/2" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

This is the same as:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "crop=320/2:240/2:320/2:240/2" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Which is the same as:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "crop=160:120:160:120" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

- You can refer to the input image size with `in_w` and `in_h` as shown in this first example. The output width and height can also be used with `out_w` and `out_h`.

### Example 3

[image: 20 pixels from the top, and 20 from the bottom]

Crop 20 pixels from the top, and 20 from the bottom:

```
 ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "crop=in_w:in_h-40" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

- The filter will automatically center the crop if `x` and `y` are omitted such as in this example.

### Previewing

You can take a crop (heh heh) and preview it live with `ffplay`:

```
ffplay -i input -vf "crop=in_w:in_h-40"
```

This way you can experiment and adjust your cropping without the need to encode, view, repeat.

### Notes

- [`crop` filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop)
- Default encoder for MP4 is `libx264` (H.264 video) or `mpeg4` (MPEG-4 Part 2 video) depending on your `ffmpeg` build. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.
- Instead of cropping and re-encoding, consider cropping upon playback. This is possible with any player worth using.
- Ancient `ffmpeg` builds used `-croptop`, `-cropbottom`, `-cropleft`, `-cropright` options instead of the `crop` filter. If this is the case for you then [get a modern `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Development is very active and there is no reason to use an antique.

Comment: This works with 'avconv' now.

Comment: I have an 1923x1080 and want 1920x1080. This the the commend I tried: `/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/ffmpeg -i /Users/kukodajanos/Desktop/video_640x480-2.mp4 -filter:v "crop=1920:1080:0:0" -c:a copy /Users/kukodajanos/Desktop/video_640x480-4.mp4` but the original movie is returned.

Comment: @Joce JFYI avconv is part of libav — a fork of ffmpeg

Comment: worth to mention this technique (with the `crop` filter) re-encodes the video, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378548/ffmpeg-crop-a-video-without-losing-the-quality if re-encoding matters for you

Comment: edited to change the outdated `-filter:v` to the more up to date and simpler to type `-vf`. Cheers!

Comment: I'm getting some automatic scale somehow. I guess it comes from the aspect :/ For instance, when I do "crop=80:60:200:100", my final video ends up being 97x60. I tried adding setsar=1:1 next to crop, but then it seems to scale it before crop, so the final size is 80x60, but the contents are the wrong aspect.

Comment: If you're trying to remove black bars around your video (piallarbox, letterbox, windowbox etc.) use `cropdetect` first to have ffmpeg print cropping parameters for you: `ffmpeg.exe -i vid.mp4 -vf cropdetect out.mp4`

Comment: For those who wonder, `-vf` is an alias for `-filter:v`.

Comment: When I use this solution, my output video has a much lower bitrate. Any idea why?

Comment: You can adjust the output audio/video bitrate with the proper parameters. Please refer to this answer to see a procedure: https://superuser.com/a/521684/83875, basically you "`use the -b:v and -b:a options, respectively. You can use abbreviations like K for kBit/s and M for MBit/s.`". Credits to @slhck.

Comment: If your video is long, you might want to let ffmpeg sample a passage with cropdetect to give you optimum values before you encode. Here's an example that gets the crop value for a 14 minute passage starting at 33 and a half minutes into the video: ffmpeg -ss 00:33:30 -t 00:14:00 -i video.mp4 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1

Comment: This crop filter works great! In order to determine the bounding box needed to crop a video, I exported a video frame to an image with ffmpeg. Then open the image with GIMP where I can draw a bounding box for the area I wanted to crop the video and then I can get the X,Y,W, H info from the pointer window. Ask if this is not clear enough.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo You could consider starting a new question if any particular part that is not clear for you.

Comment: would it be possible to do the crop just for a specific duration in the video?

Comment: @Alex, sure. You just need to insert the proper parameters in the command line. See this answer for information: https://askubuntu.com/a/59388/9598

Comment: Basically you add `-ss 00:00:30` in order to say the  point where to start the cut, and `-t 00:00:05` to say the duration you may wish.

Comment: Does this remove the cropped data, or is the data recoverable? I want to crop sensitive data.

Comment: The process will deliver a new video file which will contain only the portion of video you cropped. No additional recoverable data will be available in that file. Nevertheless, you will keep the original video file alongside with the new cropped file.

Comment: `-c:a copy` isn't included in the first command presented. What do they do?

Comment: how would i convert the result to gif?

Comment: @Kong, you can either use `ffmpeg -i VIDEO-ORIGINAL.EXT IMAGE.GIF` or `convert VIDEO-ORIGINAL.EXT IMAGE.GIF`, in both cases `VIDEO-ORIGINAL` is the source file name and `.EXT` is the file extension. The `IMAGE.GIF` can be anything you may wish but keep the `.GIF` (lowercase perhaps) to get the results. Please have in mind the `ffmpeg` will be faster but the `convert` will provide you with a high quality GIF animation. Additional parameters can be used to improve the final gif animation performance.

Comment: Your answer has mixed terminology. At the top you say that crop has `x:y` at the end, but later you define w,h at the start.

Comment: @AaronFranke, yes, you're right. X and Y are for coordinates, W and H is to clarify on Width and Height respectively. Thanks for pointing that. The answer has suffered additions, updates and corrections from the community. Nowadays is quite different from what I answered first.